# Import error Google pub/sub on gen1 Google cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, requirements.txt

I tried many ways to `from google.cloud import pubsub_v1` in python 3.11 but each time when I check function logs it says:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'pubsub_v1' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

Which is obvious that google-cloud-pubsub is not installed.

Here is my requirements.txt :

```
functions-framework==3.*
firebase-functions==0.1.0
google-cloud-pubsub

-e ./localpackage
```

I've tried both with specific version and without it,
but neither worked!
I also tried both with Google cloud website console and gcloud in windows:

```
gcloud functions deploy storage_finalize --source=on_finalize --runtime python311 --trigger-resource testproject-123.appspot.com --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize --entry-point finalize
```

but same error is shown.

Comment: Do you think it is worth to try something like this `google-cloud-pubsub>=X.X.X` in the requirements.txt file?

Comment: no, unfortunately didn't solved :(

Answer (score 0):

Was running into this on my firebase cloud functions project. My issue was that I didn't have the project's virtual environment activated when I had installed pubsub.

Ran:

```
source ./functions/venv/bin/activate
pip install google-cloud-pubsub
```

and that fixed it for me.